# Cool down discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Here is my code, I want it to send a message if the command has been used twice within like 10 seconds. Idk but it is very wrong

```
        var bumpEmbedTwo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Cool Down!!!')
        .setColor(0xFF0000)
        .setDescription('Please waitt 30 more seconds before you use this command again')
            setTimeout(() => {
            message.channel.send(bumpEmbedTwo)
        }, 5000)
        var bumpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Time to Bump!')
        .setColor(0xFF0000)
        .setDescription('Please use the command `!d bump` to bump the server!!!')
            setTimeout(() => {
            message.channel.send('<@&812133021590880316>')
            message.channel.send(bumpEmbed)
        }, 1000)
```

Comment: The delay times are messed for testing, so they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem would be to save user+command+time in DB or in some global variable.

And then perform a check.

Pseudo-code:

```js
var storage = {
  "/command": {
    "user-id-123": "22/02/2021 5:27pm"
    "user-id-345": "22/02/2021 3:12pm"
  }
};

Chat.on("/command", (user) => {
  if (!storage["/command"].hasOwnProperty(user.id)) {
    storage["/command"][user.id] = Date.now();
  }
  if (storage["/command"][user.id] > Date.now() + 10 seconds) {
    return "Please wait more";
  } else {
    return "I'm running your command";
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd argue that this pseudo-code should be swapped out for the actual code. In the current form of this answer, `Date.now() + 10` resolves to the current time plus 10ms as a number, which is then incorrectly compared against a string, which will likely confuse readers who expect this to be valid Javascript. In addition, adding to the store is currently omitted.

Comment: Great feedback, @samthecodingman! feel free to edit this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided isn't correct as your doing a set timeout without an await so it would completely ignore the purpose of the timeout. Also, whenever the .on('message') function is used, it would still carry out the command, what you have to do is to create an object: `const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();` and whenever the 'message' event is triggered, you would have to add whatever amount of cool down you want.

So here's the code:

```
const now = Date.now();
let cooldownAmount = 5 * 1000; // In this case, it is 5 seconds
    if (cooldowns.has(message.author.id)) {
      const expirationTime = cooldowns.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;
      if (now < expirationTime) {
        const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
        return message.channel.send(`Please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before using another command`);
      }
    }
    if(!cooldowns.has(message.author.id)){
    <command>.run() // Be sure to edit <command to whatever the fetched command is> and add to the (), e.g. message, args, bot, etc. 
    }
    cooldowns.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => cooldowns.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);
```

PS: the client in the arrow symbols are for you to change.
If there are any extra questions, you can comment in this post! Or dm me on discord: N̷i̷g̷h̷t̷m̷a̷r̷e̷ ̷ Jeff#2616